# Is it possible to calculate the width of this table

Tags: trigonometry, estimation

[image: Table]

Is it possible to calculate the length of x (width of the table) using the given values and any information that can be inferred from the image. If not, what is the best estimate that can be found.

Comment: No, those measurements fit a *square* tables just as well, and also a square table with round corners of (nearly) arbitrary radius.

Comment: However, you *can* calculate the width I guess if you measure the apparent width in the image, and assume something about the projection.

Comment: Please don't link to external images unless you have to. There is an option to include images in your posts. Click the icon that looks like a photograph in the edit window. Click "browse" and find the file you want to upload; it will appear in your post.

Comment: 1-No 2- Assuming x and the back 154 cm sides are shown proportional to their sizes then you can make a ratio and get  x=47 cm. But I believe x will be somewhat less than this.

Comment: okay, thanks for that!